# Rails Google Cloud Messaging with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm looking at using GCM to send notifications from my rails app to an Android app. The [getting started guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) says:

```
In the resulting configuration dialog, supply your server's IP address.
```

I'm using Heroku, so the IP address is changing frequently correct? Can I still use GCM? Was looking at using the [rails gem](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm) and I couldn't find any documentation related to Heroku.

Comment: Did you ever solve/figure out this issue?

Comment: Yep, just answered!

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this is that you don't NEED to supply IP addresses. It's simply whitelisting those addresses so you can control which IP's use your GCM implementation. In the case of Heroku where the IP address isn't known ahead of time, you can just NOT enter any IP's when setting up GCM. I implemented GCM with Heroku and it's working beautifully.

Comment: I am attempting to integrate GCM with Heroku as well. Is there a guide or proper methodology to do so?

Comment: The documentation is a little sparse for GCM (something I've been meaning to help out with). Are you speaking of a guide for setting up GCM itself, or for the server side ruby work?